# How to apply factory pattern php

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection, factory-pattern

I'm not sure how do factory pattern is applied.

If I take this code as example:

```
class Car
{
    protected $_engine;
    protected $_frame;
    protected $_wheels;

    public function __construct($engine,$frame,$wheels)
    {
        $this->_engine = $engine;
        $this->_frame = $frame;
        $this->_wheels = $wheels;
    }
}

class Engine
{
    protected $_hp;

    public function __construct($hp)
    {
        $this->_hp = $hp;
    }
}

class Frame
{
    protected $_type;
    protected $_length;

    public function __construct($type,$length)
    {
        $this->_type = $type;
        $this->_length = $length;
    }
}

class Wheels
{
    protected $_diameter;

    public function __construct($diameter)
    {
        $this->_diameter = $diameter;
    }
}

class CarFactory
{
    // ???
}
```

How is the factory supposed to create all the parts of the car? Do I need a factory for every part? If so, how does the CarFactory know about them? The combination of IOC, DI and factory pattern confuse me where everything or anything should be initiated. I see the benefits of them all (I think).

How does Dependency Injection come into play here? Every part could have been its own object but for simplicity I left it out for now.

Hopefully my question is clear enough.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use factory if you have different types of cars.

```
class Car
{
    protected $type;

    public function drive()
    {
        echo 'Zoom-zoom!';
    }

    public static function factory($driven)
    {
        $instance = null;
        switch ($driven) {
            case 2:
                $instance = new Sedan;
                break;
            case 4:
                $instance = new Crossover;
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception('Invalid driven type: ' . $driven);
        }

        return $instance;
    }
}

class Sedan extends Car
{
    // some things for sedan
}

class Crossover extends Car
{
    // some things for Crossover
}

$sedan = Car::factory(2);
$crossover = Car::factory(4);

$sedan->drive();
$crossover->drive();
```

Something like that.

Comment: And of course you can use arbitrary arguments in factory. So you can also add DI there and inject dependencies in new instance.

Comment: How do I use this with DI? With the extra parts etc.

Comment: `public static function factory($type, $power, $doors) 
{
    //...
    $instance = new Sedan($power, $doors);
    //...
}`

or even

`public static function factory()
{
    $type = func_get_arg(0); //the first argument
    //...
    $instance = new Sedan(func_get_args());
    //...
}`

in other words, you just inject what you have on input.

I think I'd rather add a gist with example in some minutes...

Comment: But where do I create the extra part Objects?

Comment: You mean how to inject them or what?

You need either to have them ready when you call factory or to implement something like container which allows you to retrieve objects from storage. And then instead of passing objects you can just pass the container, for example.